# To what extent Is Rachel in The Doomspell based on the author's real life daughter?

Tags: cliff-mcnish

Cliff McNish's first book, The Doomspell, was inspired by stories he made up for his daughter, Rachel. My edition states in the blurb "The Doomspell is his first book, and was written as a response to a request for a story from his daughter Rachel." There's a similar passage on the author's website:

> I was used to making up short and funny stories for my daughter, Rachel. When she was about ten however she wanted a story about a really, really nasty witch. This time I put pen to paper and what started off as a tiny scrap of an idea got bigger and bigger and BIGGER. It became The Doomspell.

The protagonist is similarly named Rachel, and the book is dedicated to her. But to what extent is the Rachel in the story meant to be similar to Cliff's real life daughter? Do they simply share a name, or is this meant to be a story about the real Rachel, similar to Christopher Robin in the Winnie-the-Pooh books or Alice Liddell in Wonderland/Looking Glass?

Reading the books when I was younger, it always struck me as a little odd that this might be meant to be the real Rachel, as the books are fairly vindictive to her. The scene where she believes she's transforming into a witch and live spiders start hatching in her mouth has really stuck with me! Unlike AA Milne and Lewis Carroll, Cliff's website describes him as an author of "Dark Teen Fantasy". Of course, maybe that's what his daughter liked, if she was asking for a "really, really nasty witch." Has Cliff (or Rachel herself) ever commented on this? Rachel's father also appears in the books; is he meant to be based on the real life Cliff McNish?

Answer (score 2):

The character is based on his daughter. He doesn't go into specifics about what *aspects* of her he included.

> **Do you base your characters on real people?**
>
> Not specifically, and not consciously – though **Rachel in my Doomspell fantasy books was based closely on my real daughter (for whom they were written)**, and characteristics of people I know do get fed into the books, inevitably. Mostly the heroes are alter-egos of me, of course.
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview with Cliff McNish](https://englishassociation.ac.uk/interview-with-cliff-mcnish/)</sup></sub>